# Can we generalize that all mathematical operators are examples of Relations?

Tags: functions, set-theory, relations

I have just started studying Relations and Functions from my High School book.

I am having an intuition that all the mathematical operators that we have studied up to this date are actually technically Mathematical Relations.

Sorry for being a novice, but it will be helpful if someone can throw some light on my intuition, and let me know whether it is correct or wrong.

Thanks,
Arindam

Comment: Yes, operators are functions, and functions are relations.  However not every relation is a function.

Comment: The set-theoretic def'n of a binary relation on a set $S$ is some (any) $R\subseteq S\times S$. But we often write $xRy$ for $(x,y)\in R$, e.g. $3<4$, not $(3,4)\in <$. And a binary relation between sets $S,T $ is some (any) $U\subseteq S\times T. $ Functions are special kinds of relations.  We usually write $y=f(x)$ for $(x,y)\in f.$ Note that a function IS its graph, but it is acceptable to say "the graph of ..." The word "operator" is usually a synonym for "function" but in some topics "operator" is only for certain types of functions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, when you go on to do very formal definitions of functions and operators, they all correspond to relations that have extra properties imposed on them

As an example, the '$+$' operator on $\mathbb R$ is understood as a function $plus: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $a+b = c$ corresponds to $c = plus(a,b)$.

And then digging down one level further, $plus: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ corresponds to a relation, which is a subset $ PR \subset(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R) \times \mathbb R $, where $((a,b),c) \in PR$ corresponds to $c = plus(a,b)$.

When you get down to set theory, you will find out how to define these using just cross products and subsets (plus a few other technical tools).